# Cypress not able to recognize Xpath functions

Tags: cypress, cypress-xpath

Running Cypress and came across using xpath in Cypress and I am trying the following code in .js file.

```js
/// <reference types = "cypress" />
describe ("Test Contact us form",()=>{
    it("Should be able to submit the form", ()=>{
        cy.visit('some url');
        cy.xpath('//a[contains (@href, "contact")]').click();
     });
})
```

This is how my xpath node_modules directory path looks like

```js
\Projects\node_modules\xpath
```

Here is my index.js

```js
// Alternatively you can use CommonJS syntax:
// require('./commands')
require('xpath')
```

Here is my package.json

```js
{
  "name": "projects",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "Thisistest"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^5.2.0",
    "xpath": "0.0.29"
  }
}
```

Here is a snippet of the package-lock.json

```js
"xpath": {
      "version": "0.0.29",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/xpath/-/xpath-0.0.29.tgz",
      "integrity": "some key",
      "dev": true
    },
```

After running the test, I am getting the following compilation error.
Its a TypeError.

> cy.xpath is not a function

[image]

Seems to be a small config thing. However, followed the exact steps as given on https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-xpath#readme

Answer (score 3):

I removed and re-setup cypress and xpath again using npm through git bash and it worked.

Previously, I had setup using node.js command prompt. After installing xpath using same npm command, xpath was successfully downloaded, however, the directory name inside node_modules was just xpath instead of cypress-xpath. Now, even though I had require('xpath') under the index.json file, it was still unable to detect xpath.

Answer (score 1):

In my case when i added the line require('@cypress/xpath') in the e2e.js file under the support folder , it worked

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue.
then I changed the reference types from cypress to cypress-xpath as follows

```js
///reference types = 'cypress-xpath'
```

and the problem is resolved.
This might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

[Updated for Cypress Ver- 10.9.0 in year 2022]

Use link below to install: **cypress-xpath** plugin

```
 https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-xpath
```

**Step 1:** Install XPath Plugin using below command

```
npm install cypress-xpath
```

**Step 2** Add this line to e2e.js in **support** folder

```
require('cypress-xpath');
```

**Step 3** Add your xpath in cy.xpath method like below:

```
 cy.xpath("//input[@name='userName']").should("be.visible");
```

Please make sure to check that you're getting code intellisense like this (refer image attached), once successful installation of the **cypress-xpath** plugin.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I downloaded cypress-xpath and updated the config file with requires('cypress-xpath) and then tried and it worked