# Why does 'xpath is not function' Error occurs in cypress while executing code?

Tags: cypress

I am trying to test webpage using Xpath function in cypress using VS code

I am done with the installation process of xpath plugin in VS code, and written code using '.xpath' extention. But when I run my cypress code it shows me an error which is 'Xpath is not a function'.I want to execute cypress code using xpath.

Can anyone have any solution for above issue? pls guide me to resolve this issue.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhxXB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue and found solution for cypress version-10.9.0
Refer to my @Atul Kumar Sharma reply on this SO Question for full process.

[Cypress not able to recognize Xpath function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64069758/cypress-not-able-to-recognize-xpath-function)

Comment: Yes atul sir , I have completed this process and getting extention while writting code as mentioned in your previous comment, but while execution it gives an error i.e 'Xpath is not function'

Comment: @MrunaliHood: By any chance, can you push your bare minimum code to github and share me the repo link? Please keep in mind to remove any project or company specific stuff.